# MongoDB limit the collection size

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Do we have a limiting option for collections? Maximum 10 rows(objects) for example. If I insert one more row and if there are already more than ten rows in the collection, the oldest one pops out and deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can limit the number of documents with [Capped Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/):

```
db.createCollection("log", { capped : true, size : in_bytes, max : number_docs } )
```